# Markdown.pl add special classed paragraphs based on first char

Tags: perl, markdown

I'm new to perl syntax but not to regexp,

I'm trying to add a couple of classes to paragraphs in [Markdown.pl](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) depending on the first char for example

```
Normal paragraph

? Info paragraph

! Important paragraph
```

giving:

```html
<p>Normal paragraph</p>
<p class="info">Info paragraph</p>
<p class="important">Important paragraph</p>
```

This is the code in Markdown.pl that wraps `<p>` tags

```
my @grafs = split(/\n{2,}/, $text);

foreach (@grafs) {
    unless (defined( $g_html_blocks{$_} )) {
        $_ = _RunSpanGamut($_);
        s/^([ \t]*)/<p>/;
        $_ .= "</p>";
    }
}
```

**Do I need to go with conditional statements or there's a smart way in perl which I'm not aware of?**

**Also it would be great having the chance to use `!` and `?` as first char just escaping with `\`** (not mandatory, chances I really need it are neart to `0`)

Comment: Voting to move to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Whatever will provide an answer...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got so far, it works but I wish to know if there are smarter ways to do this in perl

```
my @grafs = split(/\n{2,}/, $text);

#
# Wrap <p> tags.
#
foreach (@grafs) {
    unless (defined( $g_html_blocks{$_} )) {
        $_ = _RunSpanGamut($_);
        if ( m/^[ \t]*\?/ ){
            s/^([ \t]*\?[ \t]*)/<p class="Information">/;
        } elsif ( m/^[ \t]*\!/ ){
            s/^([ \t]*\![ \t]*)/<p class="Important">/;
        } else {
            s/^([ \t]*)/<p>/;
        }
        $_ .= "</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm completely new to Perl, and is looking to make special paragraph too. I came across this article which I think could be helpful to your situation.

http://www.pingtrip.com/weblog/2008/04/adding-custom-tags-to-markdown

His modification makes `div` with `class="note"` or `"warning"`

```
~? This is a Note Block ~?

~! This is a Warning Block ~!
```

I followed his instruction, and they work fine.